# Select a word match & Highlight the word from the entire HTML body

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate a scenario werein i need to find the occurence of a word in the entire page & then perform a highlight on all the matches.

I tried the below code but doesnt seem to get it working:

```
 WebElement findelement=driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
 String findelement_text= findelement.getText();

 int count = 0;
 while ( findelement_text.contains("testing")){

                    count++;

                    findelement_text= findelement_text.substring(findelement_text.indexOf(keyword1) + keyword1.length());
            }

   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='2px groove green'",findelement_textcontains("testing"));
```

Comment: Any thoughts here ?

Comment: Did you tried [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know if it's not exactly what you want:

```
List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'testing')]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) { arguments[0][i].style.border='2px groove green'; }", allOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... The script snippet you added fetches the entire text or paragraphs which have text "testing" , i only want to get or print only the word "testing" from the entire page not the other sentences or paragraphs along with it & then highlight all those words named "testing" ... Hope i'm clear in the explanation.

Comment: Oh... that will be much more complicated `JavaScript` as you need to replace target word with a separate web-element, e.g. `<p>This is testing of web application</p>`  => `<p>This is <span class="highlight">testing</span> of web application</p>` and then apply style to all `span` elements with `class="highlight"`... I'll try to get solution for the same, but I'm not a `JavaScript` coder...

Comment: Thanks & same with me i'm not much into Javascript coding .... Natively through Java & selenium i tried many things which didn't work here.